# MySQL LEFT JOIN Query is Behaving Strangely

Tags: mysql, sql

Mysql LEFT JOIN query is returning strange result. The query returns a record when the right ON condition "PARTIALLY" matches the left.

```
SELECT s.id sid
     , s.points sCredits
     , s.ghs
     , s.usd
     , s.africa
     , o.id oid
     , o.user_id
     , o.item_id
  FROM pi21o_zoo_item s
  LEFT 
  JOIN pi21o_logos_orders o
    ON s.id = o.item_id
   AND o.user_id = '268' 
 WHERE s.id = '268'
```

The problem is the query returns a record when  `s.id = '268'` and `o.item_id = '268-AGW'`

Comment: what's your actual question?

Comment: Show us some sample table data, the current result and the wanted result. (Simplifed, [mcve].) All as formatted text, no images.

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` will also return all rows in `pi21o_zoo_item` which have not been matched with any rows on `pi21lo_logos_orders` . Is that what is happening?

Comment: @apokryfos yes. Nick answer did the trick. thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that when you compare an integer (`s.id`) with a string (`o.item_id`) MySQL automatically converts the string to an integer (see the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/type-conversion.html)). Since `'268-AGW'` starts with an integer, it is successfully converted to 268 which then matches the `s.id` value. To work around this, cast the `s.id` value to a string i.e. write

```
(CAST(`s`.`id` AS CHAR) = `o`.`item_id`) AND (`o`.`user_id` = '268')
```

Comment: Thank you soo much. Apart from helping me solve this problem, you've also taught me something great. cheers